# How do I hide CSS until a function runs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mootools

I have a basic function that when no answer is clicked it shows an error message in 
the div id "error". this works fine but when i have a background colour and image is shows the style on the div. i'm using jquery and moo tools,

Is there a way to hide this style until the answer is set.

```
    <style type="text/css>

    #error {

      border: 1px solid;
      margin: 10px 0px;
      padding:15px 10px 15px 50px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 10px center;
      color: #D8000C;
      background-color: #FFBABA;
      background-image: url('../images/error.png');

    }
    </style>

    <div id="error"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript>
    function showAnswerAlert() {
        $('error').set('html', '<strong>Please select an answer above.<strong>')


    }
    function clearErrorBox() {
        $('error').set('html','');


    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Use classes, and add/remove them when needed.

Comment: start it with display-none then when showAnswerAlert you can toggle it to block and show your actuall alert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide the div initially and show in showAnswerAlert or where ever you need

```
<div id="error" style="display:none"></div>

function showAnswerAlert() {
    $('error').set('html', '<strong>Please select an answer above.<strong>');
    $('error').show();
}
```

or hide error div on document ready

```
$(function(){
    $('error').hide();
});
```

Comment: How you hide the error div? I added one of way to hide the error div.

Comment: Same way, as in your example. must be something else in the code stoping it from showing again. thxs for your help, as what you have given me is correct for the above.

Answer (score 1):

the reason why hide() and show() dont work is because those ase jQuery functions, if you're using mootools, and would like to use "hide()" and "show()" you need to write functions like so:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    Element.implement({
  //implement show
    show: function() {
      this.setStyle('display','');
    },
    hide: function() {
      this.setStyle('display','none');
    }
  });
});
```

or you can do this to show:

```
$('error').setStyle('display','block');
```

and this to hide:

```
$('error').setStyle('display','none');
```

Comment: Or include [`Element.Shortcuts`](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Shortcuts) from Mootools More.  That'll give us jQuery-style `.hide()` and `.show()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is a validation on a select item.
Validation can be done in many ways buti suggest you look t HTML5 valiations, this might be all you need:

http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html